# Loading PDF in Canvas and Drawing rectangles

Tags: javascript, canvas, pdf.js, drawrectangle

I am trying to build a web page to display a PDF file inside canvas and allow user to draw rectangles. Below is the code I'm trying. The problem is mouse event is going outside canvas also. How to restrict mouse dragging event only inside the canvas.

```js
var url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mozilla/pdf.js/ba2edeae/examples/learning/helloworld.pdf';

 //Loaded via <script> tag, create shortcut to access PDF.js exports.
 var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];

 // The workerSrc property shall be specified.
 pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';

 // Asynchronous download of PDF
 var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(url);
 loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {
   console.log('PDF loaded');
   
   // Fetch the first page
   var pageNumber = 1;
   pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function(page) {
  console.log('Page loaded');
  
  var scale = 1.5;
  //var viewport = page.getViewport({scale: scale});
  var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
  // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
  var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.height = viewport.height;
  canvas.width = viewport.width;

  // Render PDF page into canvas context
  var renderContext = {
    canvasContext: context,
    viewport: viewport
  };
  var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
  renderTask.promise.then(function () {
    console.log('Page rendered');
  });
   });
 }, function (reason) {
   // PDF loading error
   console.error(reason);
 });


 $(function () {
  "use strict";
  var startX,
   startY,
   selectedBoxes = [],
   $selectionMarquee = $('#selectionMarquee'),
   $allCords = $('#all-cords'),
   positionBox = function ($box, coordinates) {
    $box.css(
     'top', coordinates.top
    ).css(
     'left', coordinates.left
    ).css(
     'height', coordinates.bottom - coordinates.top
    ).css(
     'width', coordinates.right - coordinates.left
    );
   },

   compareNumbers = function (a, b) {
    return a - b;
   },
   getBoxCoordinates = function (startX, startY, endX, endY) {
    var x = [startX, endX].sort(compareNumbers),
     y = [startY, endY].sort(compareNumbers);

    return {
     top: y[0],
     left: x[0],
     right: x[1],
     bottom: y[1]
    };
   },
   trackMouse = function (event) {
    var position = getBoxCoordinates(startX, startY, event.pageX, event.pageY);
    console.log(position);
    positionBox($selectionMarquee, position);
   },
   displayCoordinates = function () {
    var msg = 'Boxes so far:\n';

    selectedBoxes.forEach(function (box) {
     msg += '<li>(' + box.left + ', ' + box.top + ') - (' + (box.left + box.right) + ', ' + (box.top + box.bottom) + ')</li>';
    });
    $allCords.html(msg);
   };

   var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
  $(document).on('mousedown', function (event) {
   startX = event.pageX;
   startY = event.pageY;
   positionBox($selectionMarquee, getBoxCoordinates(startX, startY, startX, startY));
   $selectionMarquee.show();
   $(this).on('mousemove', trackMouse);
  }).on('mouseup', function (event) {
   var position,
    $selectedBox;

    $selectionMarquee.hide();

    position = getBoxCoordinates(startX, startY, event.pageX, event.pageY);

    if (position.left !== position.right && position.top !== position.bottom) {
     $selectedBox = $('<div class="selected-box"></div>');
     $selectedBox.hide();
     $('body').append($selectedBox);

     positionBox($selectedBox, position);

     $selectedBox.show();

     selectedBoxes.push(position);
     displayCoordinates();
     $(this).off('mousemove', trackMouse);
    }
  });
 });
```

```css
body {
   -webkit-touch-callout: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -ms-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
  }
  #selectionMarquee {
   z-position: 1000;
   position: absolute;
   border: 1px solid #FF0000;
  }

  .selected-box {
   z-position: 999;
   position: absolute;
   border: 1px solid #FF0000;
  }
  #all-cords {
   position: fixed;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   background: #9f9;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src=https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js></script>
<h1>Rectangle In Canvas</h1>
 <div id="selectionMarquee" style="top: 338px; left: 88px; height: 52px; width: 197px; display: none;"></div>
 <div>
 <canvas id="the-canvas" style="border:1px  solid black" width="100%" height="100%"></canvas>
 </div>
 <ol id="all-cords"></ol>
```

If you are not able to run the above code download pdfjs.js and worker js and include it directly in html.  I'm trying something [like](http://www.powerlessdynamo.com/stack_exchange/answers/15638213_plot-coordinates-on-pdf-displayed-in-iframe.html) this. But I want the rectangles to be drawn only inside the canvas.

Comment: There's no way of controlling mouse movements in a browser. The implications of that would be catastrophic because hackers would make you click on things you didn't want to. You could use a `mouseout` even on your canvas and force the rectangle to draw right at the edge of the canvas if the mouse were to move out of it.

Comment: Or you could calculate the edges of your canvas and limit the rectangle to not exceed those limits like `if(rectanglex > canvasx) rectanglex = canvasx;`

Comment: Thank @Rager can you please provide small example. You can use this https://jsfiddle.net/La5qk2d7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
        $(the-canvas).on('mousedown', function (event) {
            startX = event.pageX;
```